# createLink to rest controllers

Tags: rest, grails

I have defined my domain objects

```
class Product implements Serializable{
    String sku
    static hasMany = [images: MediaContent]
}

class MediaContent implements Serializable{
    [...]
}
```

and their REST controllers that extends RestFulController. In particular, the ProductRestController is as follows:
    class ProductRestController extends RestfulController {

```
static responseFormats = ['json']

ProductRestController(){
    super(Product)
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Product){
    return [
               id: it.id,
               media: createLink(controller:"mediaRest", id:it.imageId)
    ]
}
```

The url mapping is very simple as

```
"/rest/product" (resources:"productRest")
"/rest/media" (resources:"mediaRest")
```

The issue is that the generated link with `createLink` directive is not in the rest format `/rest/media/1` but `/rest/media/index?id=1`.
Both of these urls work, when invoked, but only the `?id=` version is generated.
I have tried also createLink with `resource` property, but nothing works.
How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make change in UrlMappings.groovy

```
"/rest/product/$action/$id"(controller: 'productRest')

"/rest/media/$action/$id"(controller: 'mediaRest')
```

Comment: To be honest I had to change my mapping to `"/rest/product/$id" (controller: "productRest")` in order to achieve the behavior  without reporting action in the name